# Most efficient in-memory data structure for read-only dictionary access

Tags: c#, data-structures, readonly

In C#, I have some static data that could be put in a `Dictionary<int, T>` where `T` is some reference type.  The web app only needs to initialize it once, statically (it doesn't change).

Since I don't have to worried about insert or delete performance, what is the best data structure to use (or should I roll my own)?  I'm probably looking at something like ~100,000 entries, fairly evenly spaced.

I am looking for an optimal algorithm for fetching this data. `Dictionary<>` isn't bad, but I would imagine there must be something out there optimized for read-only data.

I suspect, but haven't confirmed that the range of these keys might be 0 - 400,000.  If that was the case, how would the recommendations change?  (I have a thought that I will post as a possible answer).

---

Maybe I could:

1. Scan through the data once and grab the highest key
2. Allocate an array with the size of the highest key + 1.
3. Take a second pass and store the data in the array.

Would this be better or worse than a HashTable / Dictionary with a reasonable load factor?

Comment: Seems rather unlikely that the lookup performance of a single dictionary with 100K entries is significantly impacting the overall performance of your application.

Comment: The application is effectively a search page, that searches this dictionary.  I am interested in the answer both for this app and as a thought-experiment.

Answer (score 6):

A Dictionary is the right way to go. Here is a quote from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx):

> The Dictionary(Of TKey, TValue) generic class provides a mapping from
>   a set of keys to a set of values. Each addition to the dictionary
>   consists of a value and its associated key. Retrieving a value by
>   using its key is very fast, **close to O(1)**, because the Dictionary(Of
>   TKey, TValue) class is implemented as a hash table.

So it will take a lot of time while building dictionary (calculating hashes and building tree), but will be blizzard fast to read your data by key.

**Edit**

In case you will have more than 50% keys present from range 0-400k it makes sense to go with a simple array, where a key is the item's index. This will give you **O(1)** complexity in a best-case scenario.
According to your question, only 25% of keys would be present. So I would go with Dictionary<,> in this case, I don't think that it has 75% overhead of memory to store each key-value pair comparing to simple array.

Comment: Be sure to use the TryGet method to access the key's. This way you only have to make one call to check if a key exists AND get the value.

Answer (score 0):

If it's really dictionary, trie works reasonably well. `Dictionary` (a hashtable) is another possibility, as long as you fine-tune it. Which would be faster... I don't know, you'd need to profile it, I guess. Space-wise, trie wins hands down. I don't think .NET has a trie in its standard library, but there should be some implementations floating around.