# How to store 50,000 English words so that it takes as little memory as possible

Tags: c#, data-structures, trie

I have to store ~50,000 English words in memory and I'd like to know what would be the best data structure in term of memory footprint (and loading speed). Would it be a Trie? How would I serialize it into a file? Is there anything better than that?

Essentially, once the ~50,000 words are loaded into memory, I simply need to check if the word exists or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, according to your provided guidelines, a simple `List` would be better.

Fetching time would be obviously slower than a `Trie` or `Dictionary`, but

> "in term of memory footprint (and loading speed)"

It will require very little memory overhead, and will load faster (as no indexes / prefix data structures are built).

See this [blog post](http://ejohn.org/blog/javascript-trie-performance-analysis/) for some memory comparison details (In JavaScript, but still applies).

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8570201/most-efficient-in-memory-data-structure-for-read-only-dictionary-access) answer, the [Dictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx) class is what you need. As per the MSDN documentation, you should use the [TryGetValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb347013.aspx) method to access your data:

> Use the TryGetValue method if your code frequently attempts to access
>   keys that are not in the dictionary. Using this method is more
>   efficient than catching the KeyNotFoundException thrown by the Item
>   property.

Answer (score 0):

A Dictionary object is proposed.
Read these:

[Most efficient in-memory data structure for read-only dictionary access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8570201/most-efficient-in-memory-data-structure-for-read-only-dictionary-access)

[Why is Dictionary preferred over hashtable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/301371/why-dictionary-is-preferred-over-hashtable-in-c)

For Help on implementation read this:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx

For serializing the dictionary object or the hash table read this reference:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adam/archive/2010/09/10/how-to-serialize-a-dictionary-or-hashtable-in-c.aspx

Comment: Sure, if the choice is »Dictionary or Hashtable«, then Dictionary. But their question even includes the hint that they might want a Trie.

Comment: I chose a bad reference, but my intention was to show info on the Dictionary class. A better reference would be http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8570201/most-efficient-in-memory-data-structure-for-read-only-dictionary-access

Answer (score 0):

Yes, a trie sounds ok for this. For serialising you'd have two options:

1. Use the original word list and rebuild the trie. It should be fast enough, I guess, but you may want to profile it.
2. Just use normal .NET serialisation for the type and dump it to a file. This prevents programs in other languages from reading it, though.